# How can I strip subfolder with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm deleting some translated content from my website, but I want redirect to the original language, the translated content url's are like this:

```
mydomain.com/es/mypage
mydomain.com/jp/mypage
mydomain.com/ko/mypage
```

And the original lang is like this:

```
mydomain.com/mypage
```

I was able to redirect to the original content using php, however I would like to do it in apache using mod_rewrite or RedirectMatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(?:es|jp|ko)(/mypage)$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

If you try to rewrite all the content for languages, you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:es|jp|ko)(/.+)$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

And for redirect also directories alone (ex: mydomain.com/es -> mydomain.com):

```
RewriteRule ^(?:es|jp|ko)(/.*)?$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: If I would like to also redirect the mydomain.com/es to mydomain.com the rewrite should be something like this RewriteRule ^(?:es|jp|ko)(/.+)?$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]

Comment: I add that to my answer.